# How to use Optional's map and orElseGet methods when calling a void method based on the optional value

Tags: java, if-statement, java-8, option-type

I have a Java Optional variable that I'm using as below.

```
Optional<Forms> formsOptional = input.data().get().forms();
if(formsOptional.isPresent()) {
    this.doSomething(myValue, forms.get());
} else {
    this.doSomething(myValue, Forms.builder().names(myList).build());
}
```

In this case, doSomething method is a void method that does something. As this is a void method, I'm confused about how I can use the map().orElseGet(), as I don't have anything to transform as well. Any suggestions to optimize this piece of code using any Java8 Optional techniques would be much appreciated.

Comment: How about `this.doSomething(myValue, formsOptional.orElse(Forms.builder().names(myList).build()));`?

Comment: Did you mean `formsOptional.get()` instead of `forms.get()`?

Comment: @naicolas That will build a `Forms` object even when a value is present. Better to use `orElseGet()`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`orElseGet(other)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#orElseGet-java.util.function.Supplier-), so the builder expression doesn't get executed if the value is present.

```java
Optional<Forms> formsOptional = input.data().get().forms();

Forms forms = formsOptional.orElseGet(() -> Forms.builder().names(myList).build());

this.doSomething(myValue, forms);
```

You would normally do that as part of the previous method chain, which you might split on multiple lines, for clarify, if needed:

```java
Forms forms = input.data()
                   .get()
                   .forms()
                   .orElseGet(() -> Forms.builder().names(myList).build());

this.doSomething(myValue, forms);
```

Comment: Using a constant for `Forms.builder().names(myList).build()` would make this cleaner. One might even just deal with `orElse` if the pattern to build is not using any underlying service call.

Comment: @Naman Since it uses a dynamic value (`myList`) it cannot be a constant, so that's just wishful thinking.

Answer (score 4):

You already have the best with [java-8](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html) version, but if you are using [java-9](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html) or higher you can use `ifPresentOrElse`

```
formsOptional.ifPresentOrElse(val -> doSomething(myValue, val),
                 () -> doSomething(myValue, Forms.builder().names(myList).build()));
```

Comment: I would have personally preferred that API, if methods with different signatures were supposed to be invoked.

Comment: sorry if I'm missing something, but I did add docs links for java-8 & java-9 @Naman, you mean add link to direct method signature ?

Comment: nope, I meant that resolving the `Forms` as in Andreas answer and then making use of a single method call makes more sense here.